# Are questions related to Hindu music and dance on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

As we all know Hinduism has its own music and dance.

For example,

- "Sa re ga ma pa da ne" (*saat sur*)
- Our own musical instruments (Veena, tabla etc)

And in dance, we have our own God "Nataraj" (*who knows more than 100 dances*). So, shall we keep music and dance related to Hinduism On-topic?

PS: Sorry, I don't know much about so, I couldn't have enlarged this content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally I feel that those topics are more of a tradition based than compared to Religion based.

If we are considering the questions like

- Dress code in Hinduism
- Marriage related questions

etc as *on topic*, than dance and singing should be considered as on topic as well. These questions should be tagged as [tradition](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tradition)[music](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/music)[dance](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dance) etc...

There will be two categories here,

- God related questions
- Tradition related questions

**God related questions**

Over here, questions such as

- Reason behind *Shiva Tandava*?

Can be asked, which are related completely to god, compared to

**Tradition related questions**

But again, we can discuss the dance and singing which are related to Gods, for example, Shiva Tandava is nothing but a dance, so question asking like

- Why is [Bharatnatyam](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bharata_Natyam) so popular in Southern India

will be considered as traditional based.

---

So the bottom line is, if WE ARE CONSIDERING TRADITION QUESTIONS ON TOPIC, than music and dance questions for tradition as well as god related should be considered as ON TOPIC.

Comment: I wrote about this in http://meta.hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/94/39
Unfortunately the moniker Hinduism encompasses both the traditions and the different religions of the Indian subcontinent. So either this site should be wholly religion centered or we have to allow tradition questions as well.